# setInterval issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setInterval implemented with JQuery to update a div within a protected page. When the session for this part of the site expires, the user is taken back to the public side of the site. This action only occurs if the user clicks a link that refreshes that page.

The issue that I'm having is that careless users are not logging out and setInterval continues its attempts to update the div thus creating a huge access log file in Apache. (> 12Mb per day) setInterval continues its attempt to update because even though the session is dead, the page is not refreshing so setInterval keeps going.

Is there a way to kill setInterval after a certain amount of time? Say 12 hours or so.

Comment: when a user leave the page javascript is no longer runing

Comment: just add some validation in your code

Comment: That's the whole issue, they seldom leave it so javascript continues its attempt to update the div with setTimeout.

Comment: I'm sorry, validation? What do you mean\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, the setTimeout function returns a timerID that you can use to kill the timer by calling clearTimeout. However setTimeout is only occures once and they are automatically cancelled when the user navigates away from the page. (are you using frames, because otherwise this shouldn't be an issue)

I suggest using a less verbose method and rely on AJAX and a session context to detect when the user is no longer being active and simply log them out automatically.

Comment: @John, I'm curious, is @user713170 your evil twin or something? :)

Comment: Hey John, thanks. Here is the issue I see with your suggestion. This div that requires the update is global in nature and applies to all pages within the protected part if the site. If it were on a single page, I could do what you are suggesting.

Comment: @John, do I have any other options with setTimeout being global in nature?

Comment: @Fred and Jim: No, relation (I don't have enough rep to delete his answer though). About the timer... as long as the browser is active there's not much you can do if you don't have some external source that you can query. setTimeout elapses just once (then you need to set it again) but setInterval, it just keeps on going and your not using that, right? At some point your calling setTimeout recursively and you need to figure out when to stop. Maybe you can introduce a condition based on what content is being shown but I need to have a better understanding of your situation to be more helpful.

Comment: @John, setInterval is actually what I'm using. I need to update this div every 5 seconds so I'm not sure that setTimeout is what I need. I made a mistake in my post, I thought I was using setTimeout.

Comment: Unless you figure out how to not log those requests I don't think there's much that can be done. As long as the timmer is running and as long as the browser is active, it's going to keep going.

Comment: The only difference between setTimeout and setInterval is that one repeats indefinitely while the other one doesn't. That can be a good thing but it can also be a bad thing ;)

Comment: OK John, thanks. Let me ask you... Would it be possible to use another setInterval wrapped around the one that's giving me the problem and set it for like 12 hours? Would this work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It would be a timer that would tick every 12th hour. I fail to understand how that is going to help?